# Handle drag events on a Map

Tags: android, events, google-maps

I am showing a map using google maps and then overlaying it with markers.
I would like that as the user drags the map new markers are fetched from the DB and overlaid.
But i cant find any reference to a method that can handle onDrag events on a map??

Basically what I would be doing is in onDrag() I would call use an `AsyncTask` to fetch newer markers and then draw them.So what I did was implement the onDrag() in mapview,but still it does not work.

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView); 
         LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);
         mapView.setStreetView(true);
         mapView.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                Log.w("ontouch","touche!!!");
                center=mapView.getMapCenter();
                String s= center.getLatitudeE6()/1000000 + "&&" + center.getLongitudeE6()/1000000;

                Log.w("Center " + center.getLatitudeE6() + center.getLongitudeE6() + "ol" + centerold.getLatitudeE6() + centerold.getLongitudeE6(),"DUmp");
                Log.w("center",s.toString());
                Neighbour n=new Neighbour();//AsynTask which fetches new locations
                Log.w("searching neighbors","markers");
                n.execute(s);



                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }
        });
```

In the `Neighbour` class I generate `GeoPoints` and they are drawn.Is there anything I am still missing??

Comment: Could you post the code of Neighbour? The error probably lies in how you are trying to load the points from your database and/or how you are creating the overlays.